# Solaris 11: how to hide pids of other users?

Tags: process, solaris

On the glorious SCO Unix (remind C2 security..)
was possible to hide pid of other users to "oth
er".
For example, user Jane see Jane's processes, u
ser Mike see only Mike's processes, etc..root
see all of course.
The question is:

On SCO Unix we use C2 security

On Linux we can hide processes of other users using hidepid=2 as option for /proc.

And on Solaris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found.

For the next users...

```
vim /etc/security/policy.conf

PRIV_DEFAULT=basic,!proc_info
```

When you log-in with an already exist user
you will do ps and..is the same.
This because /etc/security/policy.conf
affect users which you will create AFTER.

For already existing user do..

```
 usermod -K 'defaultpriv=basic,!proc_info' username
```

Now new created users and existing users can see only
their own processes.